# How to copy a file to a specific folder in ftp location using java?

Tags: java, ftp

I want to copy a file to a specific folder in ftp server.

```
 String server = "www.myserver.com";
        int port = 21;
        String user = "user";
        String pass = "pass";

        FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
        try {

            ftpClient.connect(server, port);
            ftpClient.login(user, pass);
            ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();

            ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

            // APPROACH #1: uploads first file using an InputStream
            File firstLocalFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"/abc.txt");

            String firstRemoteFile = "abc.txt";
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(firstLocalFile);

            System.out.println("Start uploading first file");
            boolean done = ftpClient.storeFile(firstRemoteFile, inputStream);
            inputStream.close();
            if (done) {
                System.out.println("The first file is uploaded successfully.");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is what I have right now. How can I specify the remote directory?

Comment: ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(String)

Comment: Within 2 seconds of looking at the [JavaDocs](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) for FTPClient I found the changeWorkingDirectory method...